# How to connect dbt Cloud to Azure PostgreSQL server inside a private vnet?

Tags: azure, dbt, azure-postgresql, dbt-cloud

I'm looking for a possible solution to connect dbt Cloud to an Azure PostgreSQL server hosted in a private vnet.

I couldn't find a direct answer in dbt documentation. I am thinking about deploying a bastion server in Azure and connecting dbt Cloud to that. Does that sound like a feasible solution?

Comment: Yup, a bastion server sounds like the perfect use case for this

Comment: Now I read though that Azure Bastion server can only be used to connect to Azure VMs and nothing else. I guess it's a little bit more limited compared to AWS bastion...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a common practice for this kind of cloud setup. Including dbt cloud but not limited to.

- Most of the part of the service are running inside private network and protected by firewall. They might not even have public IPs at all.
- One or few machines have public IPs and allow connected from restricted IPs.
- The cloud service's IP is then added into the white list to allow access

> In case of dbt cloud, [the IPs list](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/cloud/about-cloud/access-regions-ip-addresses)

> The public facing and real service could be in separate machine or colocated.